# proving if or not will have perfect squares

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been asked to prove and  give a reason  why this arithemic sequence,  -2;3;8;13  will not have any perfect squares?

Comment: Can $5n-2$ ever be a perfect square ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nth term of the sequence will be

$t_n = -2 + 5(n-1)$

Use the units digit of each term of the sequence to show that no perfect square could possible have that units digit.

Answer (score 0):

If $-2+5n$ is a square, it is also a square modulo $5$ and  the Legendre symbol $\Bigl(\dfrac{-2+5n}5\Bigr)$ should be equal to $+1$.

However, applying the supplements to the quadratic reciprocity law:
$$\Bigl(\dfrac{-2+5n}5\Bigr)=\Bigl(\dfrac{-2}5\Bigr)=\Bigl(\dfrac{-1}5\Bigr)\Bigl(\dfrac{2}5\Bigr)=(-1)^{\frac 42}(-1)^{\frac{24}8}=-1.$$
Thus no term $-2+5n$  can be a square modulo $5$, which proves no such term can be a perfect square.